# trigger a function on state change when condition is met

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have initial state `null` in redux store but i want to trigger a function when that state is populated with a promise response if it met a condition in state.
this is my state in redux.

```
const Initial_state = { 
     orderStatus: null,
  }
```

when promise resolve state is updated like this

```
orderStatus={status:200,message:'order place"}
```

i want to run a function in my component whenever state is changed and only if status is 200.
But if i use `if` statement it returns error as `status` does not exits in state initially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i well understand your question you should use the useEffect hook. Here is the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect.

So finally in your component you should have something like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (orderStatus?.status === 200) {
    // Do something when status is 200
  }
}, [orderStatus]);
```

I also want to suggest to define an empty object rather than null for you default value on the redux store :

```
const Initial_state = { 
  orderStatus: {},
}
```

Hoping my answer can help you in your search.